# best way to connect Drag&Drop to a function in a QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QListWidget` filled with items.

The items' order is stored in a separate document class.

I can move and change the order of the items, but I would like to update the document class whenever the QListWidget order is modified through a drag&drop.

This is the abstract idea:

```
myListWidget::myListWidget(QWidget *parent) : QListWidget(parent)
{
    /*option*/ connect(...);
    /*option*/ setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
}

void myListWidget::updateOrder()
{
    for(i=0; i<count(); i++) {
         ...function that updates the other class by QListWidget::item(int row)
    }
}
```

I have seen that there is no drop signal for the `QListWidget`, so I tried to associate the signal with the subclass model through:

```
connect(model(), SIGNAL(layoutChanged()), this, SLOT(updateOrder()));
```

This didn't work.

Can somebody suggest how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reimplement dropEvent in myListWidget?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#dropEvent

"This event handler is called when the drag is dropped on this widget. The event is passed in the event parameter."